# bash quoted variable substitution in sqlplus + heredoc

Tags: bash, variables, heredoc

must be an easy one.
[edit] i am writing a BASH script, using HERE document to redirect some statements to SQL*Plus command-prompt.

```
sqlplus -s user/pw@db > $TMPFILE <<EOF
    SET ECHO OFF;
    SET FEEDBACK OFF;
    SET HEADING OFF;
      select x
      from a_table
      where a_field like '%$1%';
    EXIT;
EOF
```

of course this doesn't work as there is no substitution within single quotes. so how i go about doing this? i cannot do something like  `"'%$1%'"`  because double-quotes still go as input to SQL*Plus and cause error.
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work without modification

My simple tests works:

```
 cat << HERE
 $BASHPID
 '$BASHPID'
 HERE
```

returns

```
 4608
 '4608'
```

This is because

> [If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. In the latter case, the character sequence \newline is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)

Comment: oh, ok, i'm sorry, i made it again :) [edit] in truth, i got mixed up with sqlplus, and it wasn't because wrong substitution, but because of actual LACK of results that my script wasn't working. i just read that variables are not substituted when within single quotes, so i started searching from there - couldn't find anywhere fast that in HERE documents single quotes DO NOT matter. thank you both for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it? It works for me. Check the man page which confirms that all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion.

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>    <<[-]word
>            here-document
>    delimiter
> ```
>
> No  parameter  expansion,  command
>   substitution, arithmetic expansion, or
>   pathname expansion is performed on
>   word.  If any characters in word are
>   quoted, the delimiter is the result of
>   quote removal on word, and the lines
>   in the here-document are not expanded.
>   If word is unquoted, all lines of the
>   here-document are subjected to 
>   parameter expansion,  command 
>   substitution, and arithmetic
>   expansion.  In the latter case, the
>   character sequence \ is
>   ignored, and \ must be used to quote
>   the characters \, $, and `.